# FIRStorageError code

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3

I just updated to Firebase version 4.0, and my error codes broke for iOS.

```
if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: (error._code)) {
        switch errCode {
        case .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse:
            //Do something
```

This above has been solved. Instead of .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse, it was changed to .emailAlreadyInUse.

And another place is

```
storageRef.getMetadata(){ metadata, error in
        guard let storageError = error else { return }
        guard let errorCode = FIRStorageErrorCode(rawValue: error) ...
```

The first one used to work, but doesn't any more in Firebase version 4. For the second one, FIRStorageErrorCode doesn't seem to be a valid function.

EDIT BELOW:

Okay, figured out the above as well. But now I have this:

```
storageRef.getMetadata(){ metadata, error in

}
```

How do I convert the error in the closure to StorageErrorCode?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, `FIRStorageErrorCode` is no longer a valid function. The `FIR` prefix has been removed in v4.0.0 of Firebase for Swift. Find out more about the migration [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide) and see the documentation for `StorageErrorCode` [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasestorage/api/reference/Enums#firstorageerrorcode).

Comment: Got that, thank you. Follow up question. Please see edit.